# Error with PDO inserting into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple form for a user to enter his/her name and a message.  This form will also have a drop down menu to select who this message is to.  So I can write a message to any of the 5 people I have in the menu.  The problem I'm having though is it won't submit to the database.  I think the place of my problem is in the php file, I can't quite put my finger on it though.  I have used PHP before but PDO is relatively new to me, so please bear with me.

Below is the code of my html and php files.

The HTML form file:

```
<form name="gradMessage" method="POST" action="submitMessage.php">

    <label>Who would you like to send this message to?</label>

    <select name="person">
        <option name="nick" value="nick" class="dropdown">Nick</option>
        <option name="justin" value="justin" class="dropdown">Justin</option>
        <option name="liam" value="liam" class="dropdown">Liam</option>
        <option name="conner" value="conner" class="dropdown">Conner</option>
        <option name="kyle" value="kyle" class="dropdown">Kyle</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" title="Your name" 
        style="color:#888;" value="Your name" onfocus="inputFocus(this)"
        onblur="inputBlur(this)"><br>

    <textarea id="message" name="message" title="Message" 
        style="color:#888;" value="Message" onfocus="inputFocus(this)"
        onblur="inputBlur(this)" rows="5" cols="25">Your message</textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my PHP file submitMessage.php:

```
<?php

    $to_data = $_POST['person'];
    $from_data = $_POST['name'];
    $message_data = $_POST['message'];
    $pic_path_data = "test";

    try {
        $user = xxxxxx;
        $pass = xxxxxx;

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxxx;dbname=xxxxxxx', $user, $pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        # the data we want to insert
        $data = array( 'to' => $to_data, 'from' => $from_data, 'message' => $message_data );

        // I changed $DBH to $dbh and $STH to $sth and changed to to `to` and from to `from`
        # the shortcut!
        $sth = $dbh->("INSERT INTO message (`to`, `from`, `message`) value (:to, :from, :message)");
        $sth->execute($data);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    echo 'hi there';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
        echo '$to_data';
    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: [FYI: `$DBH != $dbh`](https://eval.in/164969)

Comment: `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Check your logs then.

Comment: This `echo '$to_data';` needs to be in double quotes. `echo "$to_data";` (sidenote)

Comment: I don't see an opening `<form>` anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, so I don't think it's being inserted into the database at all

Comment: @TheBlueDog OP didn't hit a hard return on the first line of code. `<form...` is indeed there. I edited.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I know what you mean. I usually will go into "edit mode" to see if something's outta whack at times.

Comment: By the way, you do have actual quotes around `$user = xxxxxx;
    $pass = xxxxxx;` right? I know you're hiding creds with `x`'s but are they wrapped in quotes by any chance? If not, do so; that stands to be the problem. `$user = "xxxxxx";
    $pass = "xxxxxx";`

Comment: That doesn't explain the Internal Server Error though, the PHP will just bomb. I suspect the problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: I looked at my code and I did not have any quotes around the `$user` and `$pass` data but I changed it and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you please show us the exact error? Search in your logs, this may be a bug in your PHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[More information on PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

You are missing "prepare".

`$sth = $dbh->("INSERT...` should be `$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT...`

From there you could bind the variables in your prepared statement.

Using named placeholders:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO message (`to`, `from`, `message`) VALUE (:to, :from, :message)");
$sth->bindValue(':to', $to_data);
$sth->bindValue(':from', $from_data);
$sth->bindValue(':message', $message_data);
$sth->execute();
```

---

Same idea using `?` placeholders:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO message (`to`, `from`, `message`) VALUE (?,?,?)");
$sth->bindValue(1, $to_data);
$sth->bindValue(2, $from_data);
$sth->bindValue(3, $message_data);
$sth->execute();
```